# How to get the STRSQL version in AS400?

Tags: ibm-midrange

it is really hard to find out the version, I tried checking SYSIBM or SYSPROC but I cannot find it. I'm not sure if this will help but if I use `VER` command in Command Entry it will show this:

```
SMART Version R20.0 Installed.
Diary Version R20.0 Installed.
MSP Version 3.0 Installed.
```

I wanted to find out the version so that I can research on specific syntax for that version. It is really hard to just refer to SQL commands since it seems the version AS400 is using is old.

Comment: run command `DSPCMD VER` to info about the VER command.  That command is not part of the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STRSQL` doesn't have a version..

Or rather it's simply an optionally installed piece of the OS.  Note that the DB itself is part of the OS also.

You need to determine the OS version you're running.  Instead of running `STRSQL`  at the command line try on of these:

- `DSPDTAARA DTAARA(QSS1MRI)`
- `DSPPTF`
- `GO LICPGM` -> `Option '10'`

Also, your `VER` command entry output is not from IBM i (aka AS/400)

Comment: If it doesn't have a version, how can I look for the valid syntax for the STRSQL? That is why I wanted to look for the `version` because I am thinking that it will help me eliminate the invalid syntax I am having in STRSQL. In most cases, the syntax I can find doesn't work in STRSQL.

Comment: STRSQL just passes your statement to the Db.  STRSQL hasn't changed in 20yrs AFAIK.  Just use the SQL reference for your version of the IBM i OS, the latest is [IBM i 7.4](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=database-reference)  But there's a dropdown that lets you go back to 7.3, 7.2, or 7.1.